# How to Meteor.js random pickup data?

Tags: javascript, random, meteor

I tried to pick up data with random some like below but it seem picked up only a first one in database.

```
Template.miniSudoku.helpers({
    playGame: function(){
        var result = MiniSudoku.find({},{random:{$gte:Math.random()},limit:1});
        if (result === null) {
            var result = MiniSudoku.find({},{random:{$lte:Math.random()},limit:1});
        }
        return result;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `random` as a selector, not as an option in the query, eg:

`MiniSudoku.find({random: {$gte: Math.random()}}, {limit: 1});`

Extra tips:

1. You could also rewrite this to `MiniSudoku.findOne({random: {$gte: Math.random()}});`
2. You shouldn't use `var` keyword when you assign a value second time.
3. You should assign `Math.random()` value to a variable, because in a corner case you can also get nothing from the second query :)
4. Selecting random document from Mongo can be tricky, as they don't support this out of the box like other databases do. You can vote for it at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-533

Comment: Than you for reply I did like your suggestion but it's not showing anything. I thought Meteor.js use miniMongoDB. So it not support.

Comment: Oh!! I forgot to tell something. When I played around my browser console with your suggesion it's working well. But when I applied in my coding it's not working.